# Sanding the final coat of lacquer?

Tags: finishing, technique, sanding

I have a lacquered table top with some minor dust specs sitting in the surface of the lacquer. I don't want to sand it down and reapply more lacquer. Can I use a super fine sand paper (what grain?) to get rid of the dust without causing any issues? The surface is a satin finish so it doesn't need to be crystal clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try "sanding" it with a brown paper bag. That will be just abrasive enough to knock loose any dust nibs. It may polish the surface, though; try it on an inconspicuous area first to make sure you're happy with the result.

Warning: this may increase the shine of the surface; depending on your needs that could be either good or bad.

(It did a fine job on the table I recently refinished, but that was glossy oil poly.)

Comment: What is the grit count of the bag?

Comment: Good question, @matt; I'd love tp know what the approximate equivalent would be.

Comment: I marked this as Accepted because I was able to take the dust off using this method. But just an FYI, the paper bag actually polished the lacquer so the satin finish had a noticeably bright shine in the area that I "sanded".

Comment: Hmm. Thanks,  @Hooplehead24; I'll add that to the answer to warn future readers.

Comment: @Hooplehead24, it's not a perfect fix but you might try gently rubbing the shiny area with fine steel wool, either 000 or 0000 grade. I've sometimes had better luck doing something like this with a [fibreglass eraser](http://www.conrad.com/medias/global/ce/6000_6999/6400/6480/6483/800214_BB_00_FB.EPS_250.jpg) but that's a specialist tool that I presume you don't have and there's little point in buying just for this one job.